# How to enable TLS 1.1 inside a Caddyfile with Caddy 2

Tags: caddy, caddyfile, tls1.1

I have this current Caddyfile configuration:

```
example.com {
        reverse_proxy localhost:3000
}
```

Using Caddy 2, how can I enable TLS 1.1 or even TLS 1.0 within this configuration?

I already saw that there is the `tls` configuration but I didn't succeed to make it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caddy 2 doesn't support neither TLS 1.1 nor TLS 1.0. The minimum version is TLS 1.2 as you can see in the documentation in [TLS directive](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/tls) which states

> protocols: specifies the minimum and maximum protocol versions. Default min: tls1.2. Default max: tls1.3

In [tls: Remove support for TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/commit/2cb01d43cf1647bc46e2c7a114c952925524ebe1) you can see the commit where they were removed during the development of Caddy 2.

Comment: Fair enough, TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are still used by some legacy browsers but I guess it makes sense to remove those insecure versions of the protocol and force people to upgrade their browsers.